# Problems with contentDetails, duration and statistics from the Youtube API v3

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to retrieve the values for `duration` and `viewCount` for each video, both under videos:list api. I created a separate function that will return each video duration and statistics. The only thing that works is the playlist of videos that were retrieved and `videoId` within the `getPlaylist(...)` function. I logged to the console and this is what I'm getting:

```
console.log("id: " + videoId + " duration: " + vidDuration + " viewCount: " + viewCount); // return value in console
```

`id: xxx duration: undefined viewCount: undefined`

I never got duration to work, but I noticed that the api with `part: statistics` will retrieve the value of the total sum of view counts from channels where commented out. But it's not what I'm looking for. I want it to work with each video using:

`GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos`

But for some reason, I can't get it to work. I have the `videoId` property and as parameter, so playlistId can read it and retrieve said value for the video's duration and view count, but it still remains undefined, even when the `videoId` has been defined. Oh, and the alert dialog box isn't showing up either.

What am I missing here?

**Script:**

```
var channelName = 'ExampleChannel';
var vidWidth = 500;
var vidHeight = 400; 
var vidResults = 15; /* # of videos to show at once - max 50 */
var vidDuration = "";
var viewCount = 0;
var videoId = "";

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get( // get channel name and load data
        "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels",
        {
            part: 'contentDetails',
            forUsername: channelName,
            key: 'XXXXXXXXXX'
        },

        function(data)
        {
            $.each(data.items, 
                function(i, item) {
                    console.log(item); // log all items to console
                    var playlistId = item.contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads;
                    //var viewCount = console.log(item.statistics.viewCount);
                    getPlaylists(playlistId);

            })
        }         
    );

    // function that gets the playlists
    function getPlaylists(playlistId)
    {
        $.get(
            "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems",
            {
                part: 'snippet',
                maxResults: vidResults,
                playlistId: playlistId,
                key: 'XXXXXXXXXX'
            },

            // print the results
            function(data)
            {
                var output;
                $.each(data.items, 
                    function(i, item) {
                        console.log(item);
                        var vidTitle = item.snippet.title; // video title
                        var vidDesc = item.snippet.description; // video description
                        var videoId = item.snippet.resourceId.videoId; // video id

                        // check if description is empty
                        if(vidDesc == null || vidDesc == "")
                        {
                            vidDesc = "No description was written."; // FIX: test msg to see where it still shows up
                            $('#desc').remove(); // remove video description
                        }
                        else vidDesc = item.snippet.description;

                        vidDuration = getVideoDuration(videoId);
                        viewCount = getViewCount(videoId);
                        console.log("id: " + videoId + " duration: " + vidDuration + " viewCount: " + viewCount); // return value in console

                        output = '<li><iframe height="' + vidHeight + '" width="' + vidWidth + '" src=\"//www.youtube.com/embed/' + videoId + '\"></iframe></li><div id="title">' + vidTitle + '</div><div id="desc">' + vidDesc + '</div><div id="duration">Length: ' + vidDuration + '</div><div id="stats">View Count: ' + viewCount + '</div>';

                    // Append results to list tag
                    $('#results').append(output);
                })
            }         
        );
    }

    // return video duration
    function getVideoDuration(videoId) 
    { 
        $.get(
            "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos",
            {
                part: 'contentDetails',
                id: videoId,
                key: 'XXXXXXXXXX',
            },

            function(data)
            {
                $.each(data.items,
                    function(i, item) {
                        //videoId = item.snippet.resourceId.videoId;

                        alert(item.contentDetails.duration); // video duration
                        //alert(videoId);
                    })    
            }
        );
    }

    // return video view count
    function getViewCount(videoId) 
    { 
        $.get(
            "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos",
            {
                part: 'contentDetails, statistics',
                id: videoId,
                key: 'XXXXXXXXXX',
            },

            function(data)
            {
                $.each(data.items,
                    function(i, item) {
                        //videoId = item.snippet.resourceId.videoId;

                        alert(item.statistics.viewCount); // view count
                        //alert(videoId);
                    })  
            }
        );
    } 
});
```

Screenshot: (Update)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because when you call those functions, you don't wait the function to be finish.
You need to use [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) in Javascript.

I change a little bit your code (tested with my api key)

```
var channelName = 'example';
var vidWidth = 500;
var vidHeight = 400; 
var vidResults = 15; /* # of videos to show at once - max 50 */
var vidDuration = "";
var viewCount = 0;
var videoId = "";

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get( // get channel name and load data
        "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels",
        {
            part: 'contentDetails',
            forUsername: channelName,
            key: 'xxx'
        },

        function(data)
        {
            $.each(data.items, 
                function(i, item) {
                    //console.log(item); // log all items to console
                    var playlistId = item.contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads;
                    //var viewCount = console.log(item.statistics.viewCount);
                    getPlaylists(playlistId);

            });
        }         
    );

    // function that gets the playlists
    function getPlaylists(playlistId)
    {
        $.get(
            "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems",
            {
                part: 'snippet',
                maxResults: vidResults,
                playlistId: playlistId,
                key: 'xxx'
            },

            // print the results
            function(data)
            {
                var output;
                $.each(data.items, 
                    function(i, item) {
                        console.log(item);
                        var vidTitle = item.snippet.title; // video title
                        var vidDesc = item.snippet.description; // video description
                        var videoId = item.snippet.resourceId.videoId; // video id

                        // check if description is empty
                        if(vidDesc == null || vidDesc == "")
                        {
                            vidDesc = "No description was written."; // FIX: test msg to see where it still shows up
                            $('#desc').remove(); // remove video description
                        }
                        else vidDesc = item.snippet.description;

                        getVideoDuration(videoId).done(function(d, v){
                             vidDuration = d;
                             //console.log(r);

                      
                               viewCount = v;

                        document.write("id: " + videoId + " duration: " + vidDuration + " viewCount: " + viewCount); // return value in console
                                
                        document.write("<br>");

                        output = '<li><iframe height="' + vidHeight + '" width="' + vidWidth + '" src=\"//www.youtube.com/embed/' + videoId + '\"></iframe></li><div id="title">' + vidTitle + '</div><div id="desc">' + vidDesc + '</div><div id="duration">Length: ' + vidDuration + '</div><div id="stats">View Count: ' + viewCount + '</div>';

                    // Append results to list tag
                    $('#results').append(output);
                   });
                });
            }         
        );
    }

    // return video duration
    function getVideoDuration(videoId) 
    { 
        var dfrd1 = $.Deferred();
        var r = '';
        $.get(
            "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos",
            {
                part: 'contentDetails',
                id: videoId,
                key: 'xxx',
            },

            function(data)
            {
                $.each(data.items,
                    function(i, item) {
                        //videoId = item.snippet.resourceId.videoId;
                        var view = 0;
                        r = item.contentDetails.duration; // video duration 
                        getViewCount(videoId).done(function(t){
                          view = t;
                          dfrd1.resolve(r, view);
                        });
                        
                        //alert(videoId);
                    });    
            }
        );
        return dfrd1.promise();
    }

    // return video view count
    function getViewCount(videoId) 
    { 
        var dfrd2 = $.Deferred();
        var r = '';
        $.get(
            "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos",
            {
                part: 'contentDetails, statistics',
                id: videoId,
                key: 'xxx',
            },

            function(data)
            {

                $.each(data.items,
                    function(i, item) {
                        //videoId = item.snippet.resourceId.videoId;

                        r = item.statistics.viewCount; // view count
                        //alert(videoId);
                        dfrd2.resolve(r);

                      // console.log("in", r);
                    });  
            }
        );
        return dfrd2.promise();
    } 
});
```

**edit**

In other word this is an Asynchronous method invocation.

```
getVideoDuration(videoId).done(function(r)
```

**Explanation:**

Call function `getVideoDuration` and the `.done` tells that the function `getVideoDuration` will return a result when we resolve the promise (`dfrd1.resolve(r);`). In the meantime the function `return dfrd1.promise();` meaning that the result will be deferred.
When the promise will be resolved we enter in the `done` and we are able to do the rest :)

<del>What you see on your screenshot is logical because there is two Promise !</del> 
My mistake i didn't see the duplicate entry line.
I change the code to solve this problem.

So the first the function `getVideoDuration` will be resolve and then the second one. **When second function is resolved** we resolve the first promise to send te result to the function `getPlaylists(playlistId)`

**EDIT 25/02**

i change the code regarding a mistake with the promises.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I would like to understand what you did here and why it worked in the manner that you did it? I never used Promise or Deferred methods before or even heard of it! I always thought you know if you called the parameterized method, it will go through it and return the value. I noticed in console, it returned all the objects first then all the individual duration and view count value.Do you mind elaborating? Thank you in advance!

Comment: One other question, I'm trying to figure out. I notice right after printing all the different duration to console, it prints out the last repeated same duration value. Post updated!